# Summability of subsets of a summable index set.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Summable means that for some index set $A$, $\{S_F\}$ is a convergent real net, where $S_F = \sum_{\alpha\in F}x_{\alpha}$ and the $F\subset A$ are finite sets partially ordered by inclusion. I need help proving the following:

If $A = B\cup C$ for some nonempty, disjoint sets $B$ and $C$, then $\{x_{\alpha}:\alpha\in A\}$ is summable if and only if both $\{x_{\alpha}:\alpha\in B\}$ and $\{x_{\alpha}:\alpha\in C\}$ are summable.

The "$\Leftarrow$" is trivial, but the other direction is throwing me for a loop. I have tried going the route of proof by contradiction and assuming that one or both of $B,C$ are not summable, and hence the partial sums $S_F = \sum_{\alpha\in F}x_{\alpha}$ are not Cauchy. However, this has not really lead anywhere as I keep getting bogged down in (seemingly) uncontrollable inequalities. For example, if the $S_F$ are not Cauchy on $B$ then there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ so that for every $F\subset B$ there are $F^1,F^2\supseteq F$ such that $\left|S_{F^1} - S_{F^2}\right| \geq \varepsilon$. Since $\{x_{\alpha}:\alpha\in A\}$ is summable, for this $\varepsilon$ there is a set $F_{\varepsilon}\subset A$ such that $P,Q\supseteq F_{\varepsilon}$ implies $\left|S_P - S_Q\right|<\varepsilon$. I have tried to arrive at a contradiction by showing that either $|S_{F^1}-S_{F^2}|<\varepsilon$ or $|S_P - S_Q|\geq \varepsilon$, but I can't ever seem to get all the way there.

Comment: Since everything is positive, there are easier ways to argue.

Comment: What is positive? Not necessarily all of the $x_{\alpha}$?

Comment: That's the standard convention.

Comment: Ok, the question is a generalization of a problem from H.S. Bear's text *A Primer of Lebesgue Integration* (prob 11, chapter 2 if anyone has it). The question doesn't seem to imply anything about the sign of the $x_{\alpha}$'s, but I'm remembering an earlier problem that proved that if the $x_{\alpha}$ are summable then the positive and negative ones are. So I'll try splitting the sets up into positive, zero, and negative parts.